# Can field "Version Name" in "Installed Package Detail" view be retrieved via API or SOQL?

Tags: soql, managed-package, metadata-api

Can field "Version Name" in "Installed Package Detail" view be retrieved via API or SOQL?

So far I've checked the `Publisher` via SOQL and `InstalledPackage` via Metadata API, and have not been able to find this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that in the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_installedsubscriberpackage.htm). Here's a query you can use to get started:

```
SELECT Id, SubscriberPackageId, SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix,
      SubscriberPackage.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.Id,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.MajorVersion,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.MinorVersion,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.PatchVersion,
      SubscriberPackageVersion.BuildNumber
   FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage
   ORDER BY SubscriberPackageId
```

SubscriberPackageVersion.Name is the field you're apparently interested in.

You can access the Tooling API in Apex via an HttpRequest using the endpoint:

```
/services/data/v47.0/tooling/query?q=select...
```